# Git how do I fix a bad/missing commit?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am brand new to Git, and I created a first repository, checked it out in IntelliJ, made my edits, and committed. The commit succeeded, and I got the id, however, IntelliJ used a different e-mail address (not the one that was in my credentials when I created the API token that it used, not sure where it got the e-mail address from)

The commit contained 110 files, and I can not find it anywhere. When I log in to Github, only the original README and .gitignore files are there, unchanged. If I check out in IntelliJ, it checks out my 110 new files. What do I need to do to get these files to show up as part of my repository?

Comment: Did you push to your origin?

Comment: As far as I can tell. I pulled down the head/origin, and then checked back in (I come from SVN world, can you tell?) to the same. According to the log in IntelliJ, the source was origin/master, and the commit was to HEAD master.

Comment: Try `git push origin master` from CLI

Comment: It looks like you didn't push. Commits are local only. You need to push to make your local history visible on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I hit commit instead of commit and push and that is where it all went wrong. Thank you for the help all!

Answer (score 0):

For correcting your email address follow steps mentioned in the below link : `https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/`

Secondly for missing the committed file changes, if those **files are new** you need to do
**a)** `git add .` and then followed by **b)** `git commit -m "your message here"` **c)** `git push origin 'branch-name'`